# Understanding code drawing .obj in modern OpenGL and setting different positions

Tags: c++, opengl, wavefront

I'm watching modern OpenGL tutorial and I don't fully understand code that draws .obj file. I mean it works pretty nice but I've got a little problem with changing position of displayed object.

Vertex arrays are generated by glGenVertexArrays() and I think there is the line I should change, but don't know how.

There's code I use:

```
Mesh::Mesh(const std::string& fileName)
{
    InitMesh(OBJModel(fileName).ToIndexedModel());
}

void Mesh::InitMesh(const IndexedModel& model)
{
    m_numIndices = model.indices.size();

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &m_vertexArrayObject);
    glBindVertexArray(m_vertexArrayObject);

    glGenBuffers(NUM_BUFFERS, m_vertexArrayBuffers);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vertexArrayBuffers[POSITION_VB]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(model.positions[0]) * model.positions.size(), &model.positions[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vertexArrayBuffers[TEXCOORD_VB]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(model.texCoords[0]) * model.texCoords.size(), &model.texCoords[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vertexArrayBuffers[NORMAL_VB]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(model.normals[0]) * model.normals.size(), &model.normals[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vertexArrayBuffers[INDEX_VB]);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(model.indices[0]) * model.indices.size(), &model.indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

My object is drawing from (0,0,0) position and I want it to be translated (-1.0f) on the Y axis. I know how to translate matrixes but don't know how to manage with .obj.

EDIT:
Thanks for your answers

My vs code looks as follow:

```
#version 330

uniform mat4 P;
uniform mat4 V;
uniform mat4 M;


layout (location=0) in vec4 vertex;
layout (location=2) in vec2 texCoord; 

out vec2 i_tc;

void main(void) {
    gl_Position=P*V*M*vertex;
    i_tc=texCoord;
}
```

Comment: Changing the perspective is something you do in the actual render call, not in the mesh. The vertex shader code should contain code that takes input from an `in` vertex attribute and assigns it to `gl_Position`. Apply your transformation there, preferably by way of a `mat4` uniform that embodies the translation. If all this is Chinese to you, post your shader code (and drawing code) so we can give concrete advice.

Comment: That setup is very standard: you have three uniform matrices, one for Projection, View and Model. See [open.gl](https://open.gl/transformations) for a discussion on what each of these matrices does and how they work together, but the short gist is that you should set the `M` matrix's rotation part to the identity matrix and its translation part to `(0,-1,0)`

Comment: It works now, you guys are amazing, thank you so much!

Comment: Wavefront is already parsed, you'r function just binding this data to the shader GPU program. Check the code which transferring  M,V and P matrices as uniforms. You need to translate View matrix. P.S. it is better idea to transfer pre- multipled MVP matrix to shared to improve rendering performance.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is "how can I move the obj in space" it is done (in modern opengl) using Translation matrix and the MVP matrix in a shader (Model View Projection) matrix. 
Your code alone, just sets up the vertices on the gpu to be drawn, but does not draw at all.

You will need a glDrawElements operation after choosing the buffer. 
Also, you will need to set up the shader and the matrices or the obj will always be rendered on the origin point (0.,0.).

If you have the glDraw, you need to show the shader you are using.